# Display ellipse in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to write code to display square first and then two ellipse orthogonal to each other inside the square box. Please help me. I am new to Matlab. I know all the basics of matlab.

Comment: Have a look at the docs for the `rectangle` function.

Comment: But, if you DO know all the basics, then what is the problem? This is easy, and it is YOUR homework. You learn by doing, not by getting someone else to hand feed you the ideas. So start playing around with MATLAB, you WON'T really ever learn it until you do.

Comment: I know the basics but not on images in matlab. I am searching for tutorials too but not getting..

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work:

```
pdeellip(0, 0, 1, 0.5, 0) % Draw firste ellipse with center (0,0) 
pdeellip(0, 0, 0.5, 1, 0) % Draw firste ellipse with center (0,0)
epderect([-1 1 -1 1]) % Parameters are [xMin xMax yMin yMax]
```

You should read the documentation on drawing rectangles and ellipses:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/pderect.html
http://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/pdeellip.html

There you will se what parameters the functions take, and you can then change the parameters to suit your needs.